# How do object variables work in C++?

Tags: c++, object

I know that in Java, when you assign a class to a variable (eg. `ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>()`), the variable is a reference to the object.  In C++, if I write `vector<int> list`, is this also a reference?  But if it's a reference, why is it that when I pass an object into a function, it's copied again?  What exactly is stored inside `list`?

When I return an object (eg. with a function header `vector<int> make_vector(){...}`), am I returning a reference to a new clone of the local object?

Comment: C has pointers.  C++ introduces references (and very useful they are too).  But, the strange thing is that Java "reference" actually behave very like C pointers, and they don't behave much like C++ references.  So the word "reference" can be a bit confusing if you jump between the languages.

Comment: @Praetorian: Meh, I actually think it's a fairly reasonable question. And I'm not totally sure that all C++ books explain this properly.

Comment: I agree with @KerrekSB. Answering this question would be useful to any Java programmers. Unfortunately I think it is hard to answer well. I agree with everything said by KerrekSB below BUT I don;t think it is much use to a novice Java programmer as it stands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By comparison to Java, I would say that "C++ has unconstrained variables". A variable in C++ can be an object, and any object type can be the type of a variable.

Moreover, C++ has variables that are *not* objects (namely variables of reference type), and not all objects are variables (namely dynamically created objects).

Just like in Java, variables in C++ are *scoped* (or rather, it is the *name* of the variable that is scoped). However, when a variable *is* an object, then the object itself has the same scope as the variable, which gives C++ its expressiveness and power, since you can manage the lifetime of most objects as easily as you manage the scope of variables.

---

By contrast, and with the exception of fundamental types, objects in Java are *never* variables, and variables are never objects. Rather, variables are opaque "handles" that may (or may not) handle an object. The object itself, however, remains intangible, and its lifetime is non-deterministic.

---

As for calling functions: You don't really pass *variables* to functions. Rather, you *evaluate function call expressions*, which in turn entails the evaluation of the function argument expressions. Expressions have values, and values are *always* objects. However, a function value may be bound either to an object or to a reference variable (i.e. the formal function parameter), and respectively the object is either copied or not. In Java, since there is only one kind of variable, you always pass the opaque object handle as a function argument, and the handle is copied, i.e. you end up with *two* handles, both for the same object (or none, if the handle's value is `null`).

---

I'm not really sure what the correct terminology for Java variables is. I should like to call them "references", though that's somewhat confusing if you talk about C++ and Java simultaneously a lot. People who grew up with a language like C may like to call them "pointers" (since they behave a lot like pointers in C and C++), but that doesn't really mean anything intrinsically within Java. (Although for some reason Java has an exception called "Null pointer exception", but that name is going to be terribly difficult to explain to anyone who only knows Java and nothing else.)

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain your objection?

Answer (score 0):

There are four types of variable in C++ Static/Thread/Automatic/Dynamic storage duration objects. But to keep the discussion simple let us concentrate on the two most common (Automatic/Dynamic).

#### Automatic Variables.

These are created at the point of declaration and destroyed when they go out of scope.

```
void func1();
{
    MyClass x;  // Creates an object of MyClass.

    // DoStuff
} // x is destroyed because it goes out of scope.
```

The same rules applies to variables in an object. The difference is the scope is the lifetime of the object that contains them.

```
class AnotherClass
{
    MyClass   member1;
    MyClass   member2;
};

void test()
{
    AnotherClass   ac; // The object ac is created here.
                       // The members (member1 and member2) are created at the same time.
                       // and they live as long as the object ac lives.
} // Everything destroyed here.

// If we dynanically allocate ac (see below).
// then the members will live until the parent object is destroyed.
// Which happens when you call delete.
```

#### Dynamic Variables.

These are created by using the keyword `new` and live until they are explicitly deleted using the keyword `delete`.

```
void func2()
{
    MyClass& y = new MyClass();   // Creates a dynamic object
                                  // This will live until it is explicitly deleted.

} // You forgot to call delete the object still exists but there is no variable
  // pointing at it (so we have lost all references and it is not leaked).
```

It is uncommon to use dynamic variables directly; In most situations you wrap them in smart pointers that will automatically call `delete` for you. The simplest smart pointer is `std::shared_ptr`. It is basically a reference counting wrapper around a pointer. So when you copy it around the reference count is incremented as the variables are destroyed the count decrements and when it reaches zero it is destroyed.

```
void func3()
{
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass>  z  = new MyClass(); // This is the closes we have to a Java variable
                                                  // It is reference counted.
                                                  // When no more values exist then it is deleted.

    std::shared_ptr<MyClass>  a  = z;             // a and z point (refer) to the same object.
 }
 // The object is destroyed (because both a and z are automatic variables).
 // At this point they have gone out of scope decrementing the count.
 // The count reached zero and the object was destroyed (with delete)
```

#### References

The problem with the term reference is that it is overladed across languages and means different things in the two languages.

In Java all variables are references (ignoring java primitive types). There is an object out there somewhere (created by new) and you can have a bunch of variables that reference that object. To most C/C++ programmers this sounds exactly like a pointer.

```
void myJavaFunc()
{
     MyClass  a   = new MyClass;
     MyClass  b   = a;             // both a and b refer to the same variable.

     //
     b.doStuff();   // Both 'a' and 'b' refer to the same object.
                    // So anything you do via b is visable to 'a'
}
```

The GC keeps track of how many references there are to an object and when this reaches zero it cleans it up.

In C++ a reference is another name to an existing object (It is an alias). Once created the reference can not change the object it is aliasing.

```
void MyCPPFunc()
{
     MyClass  a;           // Creates a local object.
     MyClass& b = a;       // Creates a reference variable b that is an alias for a.

     //
     b.doStuff();   // Both 'a' and 'b' refer to the same object.
                    // So anything you do via b is visable to 'a'
 }
```

Differences.
In C++ variables and references can not be NULL.
In C++ references can not be reseated (made to point at another object).

Note. In C++ pointers can be NULL (but not objects).

### Back to the Question:

#### Question 1:

> If I write vector list, is this also a reference? But if it's a reference, why is it that when I pass an object into a function, it's copied again? What exactly is stored inside list?

```
vector<int>    list;      // This creates an object in the local scope.

vector<int>&   A = list;  // This creates a reference to the list object.
vector<int>    B = list;  // This creates a new object B that is a copy of list.
```

When you call functions you can use object or references as the parameter type.

```
 void myDoStuffOne(vector<int>  p1)
 {
      // Here p1 is an object.
      // because it is an object it is created as a copy of the parameter
      // that was passed at the call point.
      //
      // Since they are different objects manipulating p1 does not change
      // the value of the original variable.
 }

 void myDoStuffTwo(vector<int>&  p1)
 {
      // Here p1 is a reference.
      // because it is an reference it is alias of the parameter that was passed.
      // at the call point. So it refers to the same object.
      //
      // Any action on this object is the same as manipulating the original
      // object and you can see the difference when the function returns.
 }

 // also worth noting are const reference parameters.
 void myDoStuffThress(vector<int> const&  p1)
 {
      // Here p1 is a const reference.
      // Just like a normal reference except the function is not allowed to 
      // mutate the state of the object (also useful for passing temporary objects).
 }
```

#### Question 2:

> When I return an object (eg. with a function header vector make_vector(){...}), am I returning a reference to a new clone of the local object?

So a function like this:

```
 std::vector<int> make_vector()
 {
       std::vector<int>   result;

       // fill vector in some way.

       return result;
 }
```

When you return an object by value then you must copy the object out of the function. So technically yes a copy should be made. (Note if your are returning a local object you must return by value. If you are returning a member of an object you can return by reference (or const reference)).

**BUT** in reality is a copy made. The answer is invariably no.

In C++03 the compiler is highly optimized and return copies are eliminated (technique is called RVO and NRVO optimization). The resulting object is created at the point it is needed outside the function. This works 99% (made up stat but it is highly efficient) of the time.

In C++11 A new technique has been added that resolves the remaining 1% of issues.
When the object is returned by value its content are not copied but moved (this usually involves copy a couple of pointers around and is usually very trivial).

Comment: No such thing as "dynamic variables". The "four things" you mention at the beginning are *storage classes*, and *objects* have storage, not variables.